# Infragistics xamChart databind datetime column from a datatable?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, charts, infragistics

Need to show data in following format via xamChart:

```
time   | v1  | v2  | ... | vn
-------+-----+-----+-   -+-----
t1     |     |     | ... |       
t2     |     |     | ... |  
...    .     .     . ... . 
tm     |     |     | ... |
```

Where `v1 - vn` are design time unknown labels (*n* is also unknown). `t1 - tm` are datetime values I want on X axis. Other cell contain some figures.

What I need is a chart like the one below but with time as X axis labels instead of just indices.

[image: xamChart]

Here's the code I use:

```
foreach (var column in dataTable.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Skip(1))
{
    var s = new Series
                {
                    DataSource = dataTable,
                    DataMapping = column.ColumnName,
                    ChartType = ChartType.Line,
                    Label = column.ColumnName,
                };

    queriesChart.Series.Add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the XamDataChart using a CategoryDateTimeAxis with a DataTemplate for the Label:

```
<ig:CategoryDateTimeXAxis 
    x:Name="xmXAxis" 
    DateTimeMemberPath="Label"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    Label="{StaticResource XAxisLabelTemplate }">
```

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="XAxisLabelTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Date, Converter={StaticResource igStringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=MM/dd/yy}" 
                    TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#CCCCCC" Height="15" Width="65" Margin="0,4,0,0"/>                 
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item, Converter={StaticResource igStringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=T}"
                    TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#CCCCCC" Height="15" Width="65"/>
    </StackPanel>   
</DataTemplate>
```

Converter:

```
class igStringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;
        string fmtDt = String.Format("{0:" + parameter.ToString() + "}", dt);          
        return fmtDt;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```